# How can i calculate A and Y if i know C and X in this XOR function X = Y^(A^C) (binary code)

Tags: binary, logic, bit, xor

i have this function: ***x = y^(a^c)***
where **^** symbol is the XOR logic between binary numbers,
and i have only **x** and **c** variables, how can i calculate **y** and **a**?
I am trying in every way to solve but I can not understand how to reverse it, does anyone know how to help me?
Or, if in this way it is not possible to trace the variables, which function (with the same variables) but with different logic gates, can be reversible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You have one equation but two unknowns.

Best you can get is a simpler equation relating y and a (and merging x and a, the knowns, into one value), and then you can, given one y/a, calculate the corresponding a/y.

Comment: can you show me an example? i can't see the solution in my mind, thanks

Comment: some hints: XOR is associative and commutative, and `b^z^z == b` (any b, z), so now you know how to move variables from one side to the other. you should be able to arrive at `y ^ a == x ^ c` where the RHS is a constant (you know x and c), or `a == y ^ (x^c)`

Comment: Do you think there would be a way, using decimal numbers instead of binary numbers, also normal operations instead of logic gates, to reconstruct the two variables also limiting the length of the variable x as much as possible? (maximum 30-35 digits)
I have to memorize the same variable in this way but about 100 times, its value is about 5287941256 each time, in the end I would need a not very big variable x. Thanks

Comment: no, same principle.